# JS Promises: Promises are executing/resolving when assigning to a variable

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to assign a `new Promise()` to a variable and then push that variable to an array, resulting in an array of promises. I then want to execute this array of promises later on within a button click.

But when assigning the `Promise` to the variable, it just executes straight away.

```
ProcessExamples(){
    swal({
        title : 'Get Examples?',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
    }).then( aRes => {
        if( aRes.value ){
            let lAllPromises = ExampleClass.GetExamplePromises();
        }
    });
}

static GetExamplePromises(){
    let lPromises = [];
    Examples.forEach( aExample => {
        let lPromise = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            resolve( true );
        });
        lPromises.push( lPromise );
    });
    return lPromises;
}
```

By the time the array of promises is returned to the `ProcessExamples` method, all the promises have been resolved. This is not what I want, what can I do?

I've tried replacing the lambda `( resolve, reject ) => {}` with `function( resolve, reject ) {}` - that did nothing.

I've identified that it resolves before it's even been pushed to the `Promises` array, so I'm assuming it's happening when being assigned to `lPromise`

Comment: Does it really matter? If you want to ensure there's some sort of delay in there, do `setTimeout(resolve, 5000)`. Otherwise, you have a resolved promise, and you can *chain* something to it (`p.then(...)`) whenever you want…

Comment: "*I then want to execute this array of promises later*" - that's not how promises work. A promise represents the result of an asynchronous task, not the computation itself, it cannot be "executed". Use a function to call instead.

Comment: "*all the promises have been resolved*" - well, you are resolving them immediately with `resolve(true)`. When else would you expect that to happen?

Comment: @Bergi I was assuming I add the Promises to my array and execute them later with `Promise.all(lAllPromises)`

Comment: No, as I said promises cannot be executed from outside. All that `Promise.all` does is create a new promise which observes the promises in the array. But even if `Promise.all(lAllPromises)` *did* "execute them", how would `ExampleClass.GetExamplePromises()` behave differently? It still would return an already-resolved ("executed") promise.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you could post your real code that demonstrates why you are using promises at all, not the immediately-fulfilled toy example.

Comment: @Bergi I tested with both the real code and this example, they produced the same issue.

Comment: @KesWalker There is no issue, the code works exactly is it should. If what it is doing is not what you wanted, you need to tell us what you wanted it to do instead so that we can suggest how to write the code differently - and that works better if you post your real code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But when assigning the Promise to the variable, it just executes straight away.

Yes, that is what the Promise constructor does (it executes its callback function immediately and passes it resolve and reject functions that the callback can call when it is finished).

If you want something you can execute later, then use a function instead of a promise. (The function could return a promise).